# Get unmerged data from source tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have got two dataframes:

```
df1 = (data = {'Invoice' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                            'Value' : [10, 25, 40, 10, 15]})

     Invoice    Value  Param
0        1     10      0
1        2     25      0
2        3     40      0
3        4     10      0
4        5     15      0

df2 = (data = {'Invoice' : [2, 3, 5, 2],
                'Value' : [25, 15, 15,25],
                'TestData': ["A",'B','C','D']})

   Invoice    TestData  Value  Param
0        2        A     25      0
1        3        B     15      0
2        5        C     15      0
3        2        D     25      1
```

I don't want to merge two times invoice no 2 from df2 with single occurence in df1, so:

```
df1["Param"]=df1.groupby(["Invoice","Value"]).cumcount()
df2["Param"]=df2.groupby(["Invoice","Value"]).cumcount()
```

After merging:

```
df3 = (df1,df2, left_on=["Invoice","Value","Param"], right_on=["Invoice","Value","Param"])`
```

there is final, merged, dataframe:

```
     Invoice    Value   Param TestData 
0     2      25      0      A 
1     5      15      0      C
```

Now I want to get unmerged data from df1:

```
df1[(~df1.Invoice.isin(df3.Invoice))&(~df1.Value.isin(df3.Value))]`
```

and it works fine for df1:

```
    Invoice Value   Param
0   1     10      0
2   3     40      0
3   4     10      0
```

but fails for df2 where result is empty dataframe:

```
df2[(~df2.Value.isin(df3.Value))&(~df2.Invoice.isin(df3.Invoice))]`
```

As far as I check this, I think comparision runs "twice" instead of once (& operator) -  the code checking number of each invoice first, and then again check value **independently** instead of checking two conditions at the same time.

Have you got any idea how to get unmerged df2 in this shape:

```
         Invoice   TestData   Value   Param
1        3        B     15      0
3        2        D     25      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated with "Param" added to merge

One way to do this, to find "unmerged" data in from both dataframes is to use `how='outer'` and `indicator=True`.  This will show you a dataframe with a column `_merge` with three values, 'both' indicates a sucessful merge, 'left_only' means "unmerged" data from df1 and 'right_only' means "unmerged" data from df2.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Invoice' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                            'Value' : [10, 25, 40, 10, 15]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Invoice' : [2, 3, 5, 2],
                'Value' : [25, 15, 15,25],
                'TestData': ["A",'B','C','D']})
df1["Param"]=df1.groupby(["Invoice","Value"]).cumcount()
df2["Param"]=df2.groupby(["Invoice","Value"]).cumcount()

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on=["Invoice","Value","Param"], 
               right_on=["Invoice","Value","Param"],
               how='outer', indicator=True)

df3
```

Output:

```
   Invoice  Value  Param TestData      _merge
0        1     10      0      NaN   left_only
1        2     25      0        A        both
2        3     40      0      NaN   left_only
3        4     10      0      NaN   left_only
4        5     15      0        C        both
5        3     15      0        B  right_only
6        2     25      1        D  right_only
```

To get inner join full merged data:

```
df3.query('_merge == "both"')
```

Output:

```
   Invoice  Value  Param TestData _merge
1        2     25      0        A   both
4        5     15      0        C   both
```

To get "unmerged" data from df1

```
df3.query('_merge == "left_only"')

   Invoice  Value  Param TestData     _merge
0        1     10      0      NaN  left_only
2        3     40      0      NaN  left_only
3        4     10      0      NaN  left_only
```

And, to get "unmerged data from df2

```
df3.query('_merge == "right_only"')

   Invoice  Value  Param TestData      _merge
5        3     15      0        B  right_only
6        2     25      1        D  right_only
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! I'm verry sorry Scott, but after I saw your last result table I realized that i forgot "Param" in merging code, but output dataframes and everything else was ok. I've already added this to code, so now it's ok. I'll check your solution but I think I did this before asking a question - that "Param" changes a lot:/

Comment: You're right! Thank you very much for help!!! I don't get it how it works but I'll learn it:)

Comment: Oh... it does a full outer join.  Are you familiar with database outer joins?  Then, it labels records which would have been inner joined, and the labels those records that didn't inner join based on its source.

Comment: Thank you! It's clear now:) I'm completetly new (two weeks of learning) in python, sql etc, so every new idea is precious:)

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question, because the end result is rows from df3. How would you achieve this and get the unmarked rows from the original df1?

Comment: @Boris You could filter df3 for "right_only" OR "left_only" and get the total unmerged records.